# Installing a library in Visual Studio 2019 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libraries, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to install this library in Visual Studio 2019

https://github.com/alex-87/HyperGraphLib

The instructions only show how to do so for linux/unix I was curious how I would do this for windows. I can download the .zip but where would I extract this and how do I get Visual Studio to install the library.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio can directly open a CMake project (CMakelists.txt indicates that).

[image: VS]

That said, very often projects are in theory "cross platform" but in practise they don't work in Windows because no one has bothered to test them there (mostly because an alternative would already exist or the actual developers do not care much). Projects that have better chances to work with Windows usually come also with a .vcxproj/.sln.

Comment: I think this is the approach I would like when I try to do this I get "could not find boost (missing boost_include_dir program_options)"

Comment: You should add boost to the dependencies then.

Answer (score -1):

click on project, properties, link  editors , input  and add the dependencies (with keyboards only )[image]